# Where are my lists created by my App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app

Trying to get into the App model from SP. I created as SP hosted app, published it on SP online. My app created successfully a list in the app web with some items. Now I want to have have a look at the list. How do I can see this list on the appweb?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose off the app web is to store data used by your code logic. Lists created here are not intended to be seen by end-users. End-users will however interact with these data through App part you developed that use JSOM to get/set data into these lists.
You can still consult them for debug purposes by browsing their direct URLs or by PowerShell on your dev machine.